# What is the error in blob submission to DB?

Tags: java, web, servlets, apache-commons, apache-commons-fileupload

I'm trying to make insertions and updates of an image in DB, already in blob format.

```
public static boolean alterarLogo(int id, Blob logo) {
            String sql = "update conta set conta_logo = " + logo + " where conta_id = " + id;
            try (Connection conn = ConexaoDBGeral.abre()) {
                if (conn != null) {
                    try (Statement ps = conn.createStatement()) {
                        ps.executeUpdate(sql);
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ContaDAO.class.getName())
                        .log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            return false;
        }
```

The code above throws as an exception: "improper qualified name (too many dotted names) :javax.sql.rowset.serialblob".In Db the column in question is of the type "oid".

The code where I get the blob:

```
        int idEmpresa=-1;
        SerialBlob blob = null;
        byte[] contents;
        try {
            List<FileItem> items = new ServletFileUpload(new DiskFileItemFactory()).parseRequest(request);
            for (FileItem item : items) {
                if (!item.isFormField()) {
                    // Process form file field (input type="file").
                    String fieldName = item.getFieldName();
                    String fileName = FilenameUtils.getName(item.getName());
                    InputStream file = item.getInputStream();
                    contents = IOUtils.toByteArray(file);
                    try {
                        blob = new SerialBlob(contents);
                    } catch (SQLException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(Config.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }

                    ContaDAO.alterarLogo(idEmpresa, blob);
                }
            }
        } catch (FileUploadException e) {
```

I am using Java, Servlets and JSPs, and PostGres. Where is the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A partial answer only.

You are generating the SQL statement like this:

```
String sql = "update conta set conta_logo = " + logo + 
    " where conta_id = " + id;
```

Since `logo` is declared as a `Blob` you will be calling `Blob.toString()` when generating the SQL.  The javadocs for `Blob` do not specify what the `toString()` method will do, but it is unlikely to render the `Blob` into something that makes sense in the SQL language.  Based on the error message you are seeing, my guess is that it is actually rendering the object using `Object::toString()` which will include the actual class name for the `Blob` instance you are using at that point.